# Kendo Grid: Filter On Different Property Than Property Column Is Bound To

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to be able to filter a column based on values from a different column.

I have bound a column to ID property and showing Name (using template). When the user filters/sorts, the values of the bound property (ID) are used. I want to use the values of a different property/column.

I have already figured out a way to handle sort (using `compare` function for `kendo.ui.GridColumnSortable)` but cannot find a way to handle filter.

PS: I tried using `filterMemberPath` and `sortMemberPath` but they only seem to work for server side filtering/sorting.

Comment: Are you filtering the grid by code or will it be filtered by the user thru the grid ui?

Comment: Through Grid UI

Comment: Have you enable the virtual scrolling?

Comment: No, the data is client side so no need for virtual scrolling. But what does that have to do with this problem?

Comment: With virtual scrolling (that can be implemented on client side), you can write your own `dataSource.transport.read` function where you'll be able implement your filter using the value provided by the readOptions parameter.  I'm unsure if such logic can be used with client side data or without virtualScrolling with an OData dataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talked to Kendo support and found a couple of ways to handle this issue:
if using Kendo version 2016.3 or above, the [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter) event can be used

```
filterable: true,
filter: function(e) {
          if (e.filter.filters[0].field == "age") {
           e.preventDefault();
            this.dataSource.filter({ field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" });
          }
```

but if using kendo version 2016.1 or below, the following approach works which uses `filterMenuInit` and binds the click event on filter button

```
filterable: true,
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
          var button = e.container.find(".k-primary");
          var fieldName = e.field;
          var grid = this;

          button.on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            grid.dataSource.filter({ field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" });
          });

        },
```

Comment: what is this value:"jane" for?The value must come from user input.could you please explain more?

Comment: "Jane" is hardcoded value for this filter. You can use a variable and populate it from a form field etc.